# Issue with Checkboxes and Javascript, PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I am struggling with the following PHP and JavaScript codes to have 2 sets of check-boxes filtering a range of data obtained from a MySQL database.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//http://jsbin.com/ujuse/1/edit
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        var boxes = [];
        // You could save a little time and space by doing this:
        var name = this.name;
        // critical change on next line
        $("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+this.name+"']:checked").each(function() {
            boxes.push(this.value);
        });
        if (boxes.length) {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });

        } else {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>


<?php
function echoCheckboxSet($header, $divClass, $columnName, $setName) {

    include ("connection.php");
$checkboxes = $con -> prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $columnName FROM item_descr ORDER BY $columnName ASC");
$checkboxes->execute();
?>
<div class="bgFilterTitles">
    <h1 class="filterTitles"><?php echo $header;?></h1>
</div>
<div class="<?php echo $divClass; ?>">
<?php
    while ($box = $checkboxes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
    $boxColumnName = str_replace('_',' ',$box[$columnName]);
?>
        <input type='checkbox' class='regularCheckbox' name='<?php echo $setName; ?>' value='<?php echo $box[$columnName]; ?>' />
        <font class='similarItemsText'><?php echo $boxColumnName; ?></font>
        <br />
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</div>
<?php
} // end of echoCheckboxSet

// Call our method twice, once for colors and once for prices
echoCheckBoxSet("COLOR", "colors", "color_base1", "color[]");
echoCheckBoxSet("PRICE", "prices", "price", "price[]");
?>
```

Then I am perfectly getting my check-boxes but when clicking on any of them they don't do anything.

My `indexMain.php` retrieves the values like this:

```
$colors = $_GET['color[]'];
echo "TEST".$colors[1];
            $colors = explode(' ', $colors);
            $parameters = join(', ', array_fill(0, count($colors), '?'));
            $items = $con -> prepare("SELECT * FROM item_descr WHERE color_base1 IN ({$parameters})");
            $items ->execute($colors);
            $count = $items -> rowCount();
```

----------------- Adding the echo:

```
echo "<div>Showing ".$count."items</div>";
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<div name='item' id='".$info['color_base1']."' class='itemBox'><div class='showItem'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'><img class='itemImage' alt='' src='images/$info[imageMid].jpg'></img></div><br />";
echo "<div class='indexItemText'><font class='similarItemsText'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'>".$info[name]."</a><font class='price'> - $".$info[price]."</div></div>";
$row_count++;
if ($row_count % 2 == 0) 
    {
echo "<br />"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }

}
```

Any idea of what could be going on?

Comment: What do you want to have in output of your page?

Comment: Try to do a `print_r($_GET)` PHP does auto format on `inputs[]` transforming them into array. You also should use `include_once()`, you're including the connection params each time you call this function.

Comment: When doing the print_r after checking 2 of the boxes (Brown and Grey), I get: `Array ( [color] => Array ( [0] => Brown Grey ) )`

Comment: Then you need to replace `$colors = $_GET['color[]'];` with `$colors = $_GET['color'];`

Comment: please don't forget the jquery tag, so I can filter out this kind of questions before hand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you build the query in your JS function:

```
'indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+")
```

This sends `color[]=Brown+Grey` instead of `color[]=Brown&amp;color[]=Grey`. A correct (but dirty) way to this is:

```
'indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join('&amp;' + this.name + '=')
```

You could try to use jQuery.param() ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ ) to get a nicer code.

Also, in PHP, the checkbox values are available in the array `$_GET['color']` (not `$_GET['color[]']`).

**Edit: Sorry, read too quickly.**

**Answer:** As you expect everywhere to use strings, use `color` instead of `color[]` in your JS and PHP code.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the $_GET and now I see the values are received ok, but I still cannot get my items shown. Every time I click a value in the 1st set of checkboxes (a color) the screen is reloaded with no items at all.

Comment: When you say screen, do you mean all the page, or your container `.indexMain` ?

Comment: I mean my container. It is reloaded as expected but it does not show any item (even if I am expecting all items of color Brown or Grey...)

Comment: Could you put the complete code of indexMain.php ? I don't see anything echoed, except for `echo "TEST".$colors[1];` (btw, this should output something like `TEST` plus the second letter of `$colors`, as `$colors` is a string at this line)

Comment: Just edited with the echo. Regarding the TEST.$colors[1], it just posts TEST. Nothing else... :(

Comment: Sorry again, I misunderstood your code. There is a very odd way to manage the check-boxes in your code. For the JS part the name (`color[]`) indicates it should be an array, but is actually an array of 1 string, containing the concatenated values. For the PHP part, it expects to be a string with an odd name... Pick one way to do things (either always use arrays, or strings), but don't mix both...

Comment: To get things to work, replace all `color[]` by `color` in your JS and PHP code.